# how to set delegate while passing from one view controller to previous in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I am trying to pass the selected data from the table view to the previous view controller but unable to do it and the code is mentioned below and where to set delegate in this case can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

```
protocol ArrayToPass: class {
    func selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: [String])
}
class FilterSelectionViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var values = [String]()
var delegate: ArrayToPass?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        tableDetails.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        tableDetails.isHidden = true
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.delegate = self
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Apply", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(applyBarButtonActionTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableDetails.rowHeight = 60
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func applyBarButtonActionTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!){
        let vc = FilterSelectionViewController()
        vc.delegate = self as! ArrayToPass
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        selected = false
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                print("\(productName[indexPath.row])")
                values = values.filter{$0 != "\(productName[indexPath.row])"}
                selected = true
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
        if selected == true{
            print(values)
        }
        else{
            getAllTextFromTableView()
        }
        self.delegate?.selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: values)
        print(values)
    }
    func getAllTextFromTableView() {
    guard let indexPaths = self.tableDetails.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { // if no selected cells just return
    return
    }

    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        values.append(productName[indexPath.row])
    }
    }
```

in this view controller I am trying to get the data

```
class FilterViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,ArrayToPass {

 var values: [String] = []

 func selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: [String]){
        values = selectedStrings
    }
```

Comment: in `FilterViewController` did you assign  `FilterSelectionViewController `'s Delegate to self ? , Show how you are showing  `FilterSelectionViewController`

Comment: no where to set it ? @MikeAlter

Comment: That;s why Show the code where you are showing FilterSelectionViewController

Comment: @MikeAlter where to set delegate I had posted the code

Comment: See my answer I have added example  for you

Comment: I tried by using that it got crashed at the delegate set point @MikeAlter

Comment: already I tried what u said and I posted in the code just see my edited answer @MikeAlter

Comment: I need to send data from filter section to previous  view controller @MikeAlter

Comment: NO you are doing wrong , What you need to do is form where you are showing `FilterSelectionViewController` in your case is `FilterViewController` there you need to set delegate

Comment: sorry I didn't get you @MikeAlter

Comment: Ok in some action you are showing `FilterSelectionViewController` Correct ? , For that you are creating object of `FilterSelectionViewController` , on that object there is one property called `delegate` check it . and assign it to self

Comment: yes I had done the same but it got crashing @MikeAlter

Comment: like       `let vc = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filterSectionIdentifier") as! FilterSelectionViewController` after that set delegate like    `vc.delegate = self` simple

Comment: Where it crashes ? What is crash log and also from  `applyBarButtonActionTapped`  remove `vc` object it is wrong there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153920/discussion-between-mike-alter-and-vamsi-krishna-s).

Comment: What is relationship between` FilterSelectionViewController` and  `FilterViewController`

Comment: Please see this tutorial before https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of redirection in FilterSelectionViewController you have to set delegate = self like this

```
let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tempVC") as! tempVC// Your FilterSelectionViewController
vc.delegateColor = self //your delegate
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I need to set the delegate in the previous view controller ?@NishantBhindi

Comment: yes before you are going to your FilterSelectionViewController

Answer (score 1):

Before going to the **Second view** you need to confirm protocol

```
class FilterViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,ArrayToPass {

 var values: [String] = []

 func actionGotoFilterSection(){
  // class initilization with navigation 
     let filterSection = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filterSectionIdentifier") as! FilterSelectionViewController
    filterSection.delegate = self 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filterSection, animated: true)
 }    

 //MARK: - Delegate Methods 
 func selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: [String]){
        values = selectedStrings
    }
}
```

- For better understanding [visit this link.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148448/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming)

Comment: That was the process for `protocol`, not the actual answer for your understanding I have done.  @VamsiKrishnaS

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing or presenting viewController (`FilterSelectionViewController`)
You need to assign `delegate` to `self` or any `NSObject` class, otherwise delegate will not call

Here is example

```
@IBAction func btnNextTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let vc: FilterSelectionViewController  =  // Assign VC
  vc.delegate = self  //MISSING PART
  // PUSH OR PRESENT VC
}
```